# the difference among $coef, coef(), list(), and plot() in lm.ridge{MASS}

Tags: r, plot

Recently when I study `lm.ridge` function, I find there are totally different coefficients in this function, and I can't figure out which one is correct while comparing with the plot.
For example,

```
 longley  #lm.ridge example
 names(longley)[1] <- "y"
 rid.long <- lm.ridge(y ~ ., longley)  #set lambda = 0 as OLS
 list(rid.long)   #it is the same as coef(rid.long)
 [[1]]
                   GNP            Unemployed  Armed.Forces    Population       Year      Employed
 2946.85636017    0.26352725    0.03648291    0.01116105   -1.73702984  -1.41879853    0.23128785 

 coef(rid.long)  #it is the same as list(rid.long)
                   GNP            Unemployed  Armed.Forces    Population       Year      Employed 
  2946.85636017    0.26352725    0.03648291    0.01116105   -1.73702984   -1.41879853    0.23128785 

 rid.long$coef  #it is totally different above two, and same as plot
        GNP   Unemployed Armed.Forces   Population         Year     Employed 
 25.3615288    3.3009416    0.7520553  -11.6992718   -6.5403380    0.7864825 

 plot(lm.ridge(y ~ ., longley, lambda = seq(0,0.1,0.001)))
```

[image]

How come the y-axis in example plot catches `rid.long$coef` as default, but not `coef(rid.long)`? what's the different between this two vectors? When I plot the ridge trace, how could (or should) I change y-axis component? I have also looked into the `coef` method explanation in help attachment, but I still can't tell the the differences.

Comment: `$coef matrix of coefficients, one row for each value of lambda. Note that these are not on the original scale and are for use by the coef method.`

Comment: @rawr thanks for the reminding, but honestly I am not sure the differences between using coef method and coef in original scale. Why the x-axis in example plot uses rid.long$coef as default, but not coef(rid.long)? thanks again.

Comment: do you mean the y-axis? the x is lambda. if you want to know how you can make it the way you want, then you should edit your question. if you want to know why, then this is more suited for [CV](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ridge-regression)

Comment: @rawr thanks again for your reminding, I didn't notice such  basic mistakes. As your suggestion, maybe I should go to CV for answering why question.